# How to pass parameter in RestClient get request header and to access the parameter in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest-client

I am using RestClient in my ruby on rails app to send a get request to an api of my app like the following:

```
RestClient.get(url?params1=<val1>&param2=<val2>..)
```

The problem is that I also have to pass the secret API key to access the api in header of the get request. I have no idea **how to pass this parameter in header of the request** and **how to access this param api_key inside my controller to validate the request to get access to that api**. So I want something like that:

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController

 before_filter :validate_access, :only => [:<api_name>]

 private

   def validate_access
     .... < I don't have any idea what to write here>
```

In this restrict_access function I want to check the value of api_key in request header to determine whether the request will be given access to that function or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set header values to `RestClient.get` by 2nd argument.

```
RestClient.get "/url?params1=<val1>&param2=<val2>..", {x_your_api_token: "YOUR_API_TOKEN"}
```

And in ActionController, you can get it by `request.headers["X-Your-API-Token"]`

```
def validate_access
  api_token = request.headers["X-Your-API-Token"] # header name is case insentsitive
  ...
end
```

See:

- https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/master/README.rdoc#usage-raw-url
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-headers